# Issue connecting to my Airpods from Pi 4

Tags: bluetooth, pi-4

I am a newbie and recently purchased Pi4 Vilros Edition. 
Was just exploring my Pi4 and tried to connect my Airpods to it. It shows up in the bluetooth devices, but it wouldnt pair or connect.

I get the below error when i try to pair :

```
[bluetooth]# connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Attempting to connect to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

I have tried various options as mentioned in other blogs, but it wouldnt still connect. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please describe your connection process from the start to the end between your two devices (manual actions included), you can edit your question and add the output of this commands : in a new terminal use `sudo bluetoothd -d` , open another terminal : `sudo bluetoothctl` and `connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, see the output of the `sudo bluetoothd -d` terminal. Some devices need to be POWER-OFF and POWER-ON (restart) for reseting BT conf, my BT Audio headset work like this. I don't know how Airpods work, but I think it's similary.

Comment: I first tried to use from the task bar which has "Manage Bluetooth Devices". Once i found my airpods, tried to Pair. It says "Pairing request sent to Device. Waiting for response",it will eventually time out. I went to command prompt and tried pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, but i got an error as "Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled". I tried to connect, but still it failed. When i type info , i am able to see the details of my airpods, but it wouldnt just pair or connect. I tried your command, but i got error : pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bluetooth -d sudo: bluetooth: command not found

Comment: The command is `sudo bluetoothd -d` (bluetooth daemon in debug mode) not `sudo bluetooth -d`. Try `sudo killall bluetoothd` before if you cannot run `bluetoothd`

Comment: Nothing outputs after i run the command. I tried to connect in the other terminal and same error. Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bluetoothd -d
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo killall bluetoothd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bluetoothd -d